# Loading sql scripts from a different subproject in Spring XML Config file

Tags: xml, spring, maven, gradle, classpath

I have several subprojects in this Spring project that work as microservices.
In each sub-projects, there are duplicate SQL test scripts that I am trying to centralize.

The file structure currently looks like this.

```
|rootproject
|--- microservice1
|     └─src
|       └─test
|         └─resources
|            ├─spring-config.xml
|            └─sql
|               └─h2
|                  ├─somescript.sql
|                  └─somescript2.sql
|--- microservice2
|--- microservice3
```

All of these microservices basically share the same file structure as microservice1.

Is it possible to create another another subproject to contains the sql scripts instead of having duplicate sql test scripts? Something like this.

```
|rootproject
|--- testdata
|     └─src
|       └─test
|         └─resources
|            ├─spring-config.xml
|            └─sql
|               └─one
|               |  └─h2
|               |     └─bunchOfScripts.sql
|               └─two
|                  └─h2
|                     └─bunchOfScripts.sql
|--- microservice1
|--- microservice2
|--- microservice3
```

I currently have a bean in the spring-config.xml file in each subproject/microservice that initializes a bean to read in the h2 data shown below.

```xml
<bean id="someID" class="package.to.load.data" init-method="load">
   <constructor-arg value="classpath:/sql/h2" />
</bean>
```

How can I specify the classpath to call the sql scripts in a different subproject? In this case, calling the test scripts located in folder testdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Maven, you just need to make your testdata subproject a dependency of your other subprojects.  That will place the testdata subproject in the classpath of the other projects, and your existing references to entries via classpath: URIs should work.  (You may have to mark your testdata subproject a Java project, even though it doesn't have any java code in it, so that it does the right thing?).

There are a couple of catches: you would have to put the resource files in src/main, rather than src/test, since Maven won't export src/test to other projects - but you could then add the dependency on testdata as a test dependency, so it will only see/use it during testing.  And you may need to tinker with the folder settings, or move your scripts to src/test/resources (since that is where a Maven Java project would expect to find them).

Comment: Im using Gradle for this project. Yea I already imported testdata as a dependency in the build.gradle files for the microservices. I'll try moving the test files into src/main/resources but I'm still confused on the specific classpath to call the sql scripts in src/main/resources. Does that make sense?

Comment: your `classpath:/sql/one/h2` as a prefix for each resource you need to load would work, as long as you load them through Spring as resources.  Otherwise, you could just use a regular class loader and load them with the prefix `/sql/one/h2`since they will be in your classpath by virtue of being one of your dependencies...

Comment: Yea I was able to solve it by adding the dependency as a classpath and using the classpath*:/sql/one/h2. Thanks!